# Error sending image with a Telegram Bot on Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment, telegram-bot

I have been having this issue while deploying a telegram bot to heroku and was wondering if any of you could help.

I tried to send an image using the "bot.send_photo" function but it doesn't work. I tried locally and it was just fine, but when I deploy it just doesn't show any error logs but doesn't send the image either. I am somewhat of a begginer if programming, so sorry if this is too obvious. Here's a sample of the code I am using and the logs from the heroku:

```
import requests
import telebot
import os
from flask import Flask, request
from credentials import TOKEN

token = TOKEN
img_link = 'https://www.tarotcardmeanings.net/images/tarotcards-large/tarot-wands-11.jpg'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
server = Flask(__name__)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def greet(msg):
    user = msg.chat.id
    bot.send_message(user, 'Test message')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['image'])
def test(msg):
    user = msg.chat.id
    bot.send_photo(user, photo = img_link, caption = 'Test caption')

@server.route('/' + token, methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    bot.process_new_updates([telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))])
    return "!", 200

@server.route("/")
def webhook():
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url='https://young-dawn-12665.herokuapp.com/' + token)
    return "!", 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))


Heroku logs:

2021-02-15T17:36:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
2021-02-15T17:37:35.322092+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-02-15T17:37:35.338479+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-02-15T17:37:35.158049+00:00 app[api]: Deploy aa954a21 by user 
2021-02-15T17:37:35.158049+00:00 app[api]: Release v35 created by user 
2021-02-15T17:37:36.832826+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-02-15T17:37:37.043632+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-02-15T17:37:42.154525+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python3 bot.py`
2021-02-15T17:37:47.876470+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-15T17:37:47.800539+00:00 app[web.1]: * Serving Flask app "bot" (lazy loading)
2021-02-15T17:37:47.800596+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2021-02-15T17:37:47.800602+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
2021-02-15T17:37:47.800606+00:00 app[web.1]: Use a production WSGI server instead.
2021-02-15T17:37:47.800721+00:00 app[web.1]: * Debug mode: off
2021-02-15T17:37:47.802021+00:00 app[web.1]: * Running on http://0.0.0.0:54384/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2021-02-15T17:37:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-02-15T17:37:57.145983+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/1543961103:AAGPnuf8Wt2b1m9T366nY4MzQOnIizLUUxE" host=young-dawn-12665.herokuapp.com request_id=388d5053-0f51-4c2b-a203-f770b3065f22 fwd="91.108.6.48" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=154 protocol=https
2021-02-15T17:37:57.144789+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.30.238.92 - - [15/Feb/2021 14:37:57] "POST /1543961103:AAGPnuf8Wt2b1m9T366nY4MzQOnIizLUUxE HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-02-15T17:38:01.563181+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.30.238.92 - - [15/Feb/2021 14:38:01] "POST /1543961103:AAGPnuf8Wt2b1m9T366nY4MzQOnIizLUUxE HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-02-15T17:38:01.563597+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/1543961103:AAGPnuf8Wt2b1m9T366nY4MzQOnIizLUUxE" host=young-dawn-12665.herokuapp.com request_id=53e87054-6370-4f5d-8e59-cf980f8622d8 fwd="91.108.6.48" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=154 protocol=https
```

Thanks in advance for the time you took reading this, I really appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Passing an url to `send_photo` will not work. You can pass it as a BytesIO object:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from io import BytesIO

@bot.message_handler(commands=['image'])
def test(msg):
    user = msg.chat.id
    bot.send_photo(user, photo = BytesIO(urlopen(img_link).read()), caption = 'Test caption')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I tried it out but still no answear. Checked the logs, no error or anything still... I'm puzzeled by this one. It does all the steps normally but on the line to send the picture it just freezes.

Comment: Okay, I just got it. I separated the send photo and the caption. I don't know if it was something with the parse mode, but that did it for me. Thank you again for taking the time to answer! :)